# css transformation is not working with css grid, positioning of elements problem

Tags: css, grid, css-transforms, css-grid

I am trying to apply CSS `transform` on my grid elements so on `:hover` I get a nice transition on the borders.

I am doing something wrong, most likely with positioning of the elements and the grid so it's not working.

When transform scaleX is applied, the borders disappear and won't show as expected on hover.

```css
.work {
 background: var(--white);
}
.work-wrapper {
 max-width: 1170px;
 padding: 1em;
 margin: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:repeat( auto-fill, minmax(260px, 1fr) );
 grid-row-gap: 30px;
 grid-column-gap: 15px;
 place-items: center start;
 background: #333;
}
.work-item {
 height:180px;
 width:260px;
 position: relative;
 background: var(--lilavo);
 margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.item::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 right:10px;
 bottom: 10px;
 border-top: 1px solid var(--white);
 border-bottom: 1px solid var(--white);
 transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transform:scaleX(0);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform:scaleX(0);
    -o-transform:scaleX(0);
    transform:scaleX(0);
 opacity: 0;
}
.item::before:hover {
 -webkit-transform:scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform:scaleX(1);
    -o-transform:scaleX(1);
    transform:scaleX(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="work" class="work">
      <h2>Work</h2>
      <div class="work-wrapper">
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.item` and `.work-item:hover > .item` selector instead of `.item::before` and `.item::before:hover` respectively. It will work! :)

```css
.work {
 background: var(--white);
}
.work-wrapper {
 max-width: 1170px;
 padding: 1em;
 margin: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:repeat( auto-fill, minmax(260px, 1fr) );
 grid-row-gap: 30px;
 grid-column-gap: 15px;
 place-items: center start;
 background: #333;
}
.work-item {
 height:180px;
 width:260px;
 position: relative;
 background: var(--lilavo);
 margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.item {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 right:10px;
 bottom: 10px;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transform:scaleX(0);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform:scaleX(0);
    -o-transform:scaleX(0);
    transform:scaleX(0);
 opacity: 0;
}
.work-item:hover > .item {
 -webkit-transform:scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform:scaleX(1);
    -o-transform:scaleX(1);
    transform:scaleX(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="work" class="work">
      <h2>Work</h2>
      <div class="work-wrapper">
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="work-item">
          <div class="item item-one"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

You can test it here as well.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/tj95b6kL/